# Changing a Switchery checkbox state from javascript value

Tags: javascript, checkbox

consider in javascript i have `b = 1` so i have this code

```
if (b == 1){
            $('#cstvststatus').attr('checked', true);
            // here we apply condition to turn switch on
        }
let elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));
elems.forEach(function(html) {
    let switchery = new Switchery(html,  { size: 'small' });
});
```

check box

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cstvststatus" class="js-switch" >
```

**i want swith state should be on if b == 1 (switchry enable )** but in my case switch is off and checkbox is checked

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want swith state should be on if b == 1 (switchry enable)